# Finding the null and alternative hypothesis for this problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing

**Question**

> The BEG Company operates service centers in various cities where customers can call to get answers to questions about their bills.
>
> Previous studies indicate that the distribution of time required for each call is normally distributed, with a mean $\mu=540$ seconds.
>
> Company officials have selected a random sample of $50$ calls and wish to determine whether the mean call time will be improved after a training program given to call center employees.

**My Solution**

$$H_0:\mu \ge 540, \ H_1:\mu < 540$$

However, this answer is wrong. I do not understand this question, I would highly appreciate if someone could explain it further on how to find out the null and alternative hypothesis for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is mathematically perfectly correct.

- $H_0$ - the status quo or even an adversary effect - in your case: $\mu$ stays the same or worsens
- $H_1$ - the **claim** that something has changed - in your case: $\mu$ got better

Unfortunately there are also textbooks around (and corresponding teachers/lecturers) who seem to systematically exchange $H_0$ and $H_1$.

The idea of the hypothesis testing is to find enough statistical evidence that $H_0$ - the status quo - is improbable (here the significance level $\alpha$ comes into play).

This is considered to be achieved, if the test statistic delivers a value that is rather improbable **under the assumption that $H_0$ is true**.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving two alternative hypothesis which are

- $H_0$:  the mean call time will be worsened after a training program given to call center employees.
- $H_1$: the mean call time will be improved after a training program given to call center employees.

The null hypothesis is that the training has no effect on the duration of a call.

Answer (score 1):

The correct hypotheses are:
$$\begin{align} H_0: \ \mu=540 \\ H_1: \ \mu <540 \end{align}.$$
Interpretation: The problem states "mean=540 seconds", so is the null hypothesis. To improve mean call time implies to decrease the mean call time by more efficient work of the call center operators.